# Log into work's email from PC?

Tags: laptop, email, android

I have a new job and using my android phone can get my email no problem. I have tried Outlook and Thunderbird to do the same from my PC but it will not work!

Any advice on how to solve this? Or is this an issue that the superusers at work should know? because they don't!

On my work laptop we use Windows server 2008 r2 and log in remotely! But I really need it on my personal laptop and not just on my android phone!

Comment: Have you asked your IT department to help set this up? It's the sort of thing they should be doing for you.

Comment: Also, POP3, IMAP or Exchange?

Comment: And what does won't work mean? Can't connect, can't send, receive, Outlook stops opening? Any error messages?

Comment: Have you also checked to see if you are allowed to? Chris's suggestion of speaking to IT should also help you find this out...